# Not able to run Unity-2D interface in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: unity-2d

I'm not able to use Unity-2D in my computer running Ubuntu 11.10.

Unity 3D works hassle-free.

when I type unity-2d-panel in terminal, i get the following in terminal and an error pops out and stops there.

Terminal output:

```
(unity-2d-panel:3106): GdkPixbuf-WARNING *: Bug! gdk-pixbuf loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure.
(unity-2d-panel:3106): Gtk-WARNING *: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1230:46: Failed to load image '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/slider.png': reason not known, probably a corrupt image file
(unity-2d-panel:3106): GdkPixbuf-WARNING *: Bug! gdk-pixbuf loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure.
(unity-2d-panel:3106): Gtk-WARNING *: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1234:55: Failed to load image '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/slider_prelight.png': reason not known, probably a corrupt image file
(unity-2d-panel:3106): GdkPixbuf-WARNING *: Bug! gdk-pixbuf loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure.
(unity-2d-panel:3106): Gtk-WARNING *: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1238:55: Failed to load image '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/slider_vertical.png': reason not known, probably a corrupt image file
(unity-2d-panel:3106): GdkPixbuf-WARNING *: Bug! gdk-pixbuf loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure.
(unity-2d-panel:3106): Gtk-WARNING *: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1242:64: Failed to load image '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/slider_prelight_vertical.png': reason not known, probably a corrupt image file
(unity-2d-panel:3106): GdkPixbuf-WARNING *: Bug! gdk-pixbuf loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure.
(unity-2d-panel:3106): Gtk-WARNING *: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1298:73: Failed to load image '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/scrollbar_handle_vertical.png': reason not known, probably a corrupt image file
(unity-2d-panel:3106): GdkPixbuf-WARNING *: Bug! gdk-pixbuf loader 'png' didn't set an error on failure.
(unity-2d-panel:3106): Gtk-WARNING *: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1315:64: Failed to load image '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/scrollbar_handle.png': reason not known, probably a corrupt image file
unity-2d-panel: [DEBUG] Scanning panel plugin directory "/usr/lib/unity-2d/plugins/panel" 
unity-2d-panel: [DEBUG] Loading panel plugin: "/usr/lib/unity-2d/plugins/panel/libpanelplugin-appindicator.so" 
unity-2d-panel: [DEBUG] Loading panel plugin: "/usr/lib/unity-2d/plugins/panel/libpanelplugin-appname.so" 
unity-2d-panel: [DEBUG] Loading panel plugin: "/usr/lib/unity-2d/plugins/panel/libpanelplugin-homebutton.so" 
unity-2d-panel: [DEBUG] Loading panel plugin: "/usr/lib/unity-2d/plugins/panel/libpanelplugin-indicator.so" 
unity-2d-panel: [DEBUG] Loading panel plugin: "/usr/lib/unity-2d/plugins/panel/libpanelplugin-legacytray.so" 
unity-2d-panel: [DEBUG] Loading panel plugin: "/usr/lib/unity-2d/plugins/panel/libpanelplugin-separator.so" 
unity-2d-panel: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libdconf-qt.so.0: undefined symbol: _ZNK15QDBusConnection15internalPointerEv
```

Please help

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

To launch Unity 2D, you have to choose it at login, you can't call it inside a Unity 3D session. There is a sort of configuration icon on your user account at login that lets you to choose between Unity and Unity 2D.
You can see it clearly here:

http://www.chimerarevo.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/lightdm-ubuntu-11.10-tema-default.jpeg